# Program throws SocketException when trying to send hundreds of http requests simultaneously

Tags: c#, http

I have written an API endpoint and created a simple .net core console app to send off multiple requests to the API endpoint simultaneously to test how the API endpoint works

The code looks as below

```
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        // ARRANGE

        int request_number = 200;
        Task<HttpResponseMessage>[] tasks = new Task<HttpResponseMessage>[request_number];
        Action[] actions = new Action[request_number];

        for (int i = 0; i < request_number; i++)
        {
            int temp = i;
            actions[temp] = () =>
            {
                tasks[temp] = CallMyAPI();
            };
        }


        // ACT
        Parallel.Invoke(actions);
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);


        // ASSERT
        string sample1 = await tasks[0].Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        for (int i = 1; i < request_number; i++)
        {
            string toBeTested = await tasks[i].Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (toBeTested != sample1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong! i = " + i);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("finished");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to complete...");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CallMyAPI()
    {


        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;

        string contentString = "some json string as http body";
        request.Content = new StringContent(contentString, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        request.RequestUri = new Uri("http://myAPIendpoint.com");

        HttpResponseMessage response;
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
        }

        return response;
    }
```

So basically what I have been trying to do by the code is to send off multiple requests once, and wait and record all the responses. Then I compare them to verify that they all return the same response.

Initially, when I set the variable `request_number` as small numbers, like 50, 100, the test app runs well. However, as the `request_number`goes up and reaches around 200, it starts to throw an exception that looks like:

`Inner Exception 1:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.`

`Inner Exception 2:
SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request`

What is this kind of exception supposed to mean?

Comment: Could it be you reached the limit of your api? or some throttle limitation.Some services might perceive this as a DOS attempt

Comment: @Robbert Draaisma I thought about the possibility of my api limit as well. But when I switch to use JMeter to send off requests, I can send off up to 400 requests once without receiving any error. All the responses from my api are normal responses

Comment: Oke that is odd, offcourse jmeter is build for this sort of stuff so it might simply be related with the code you use to call the API(in that it isn't as efficient as jmeter).Just out of curiosity isn't wrapping the calls into a list of actions overhead? simply collecting a list of Tasks and than doing the await WhenAll should be equivalent to the current code.

Comment: @Robbert Draaisma because I thought that to make a list of Tasks I will need a for loop to add the items one by one, and the items in the first slots of the list will be started earlier. To me that doesn't look like strict concurrency

Comment: this might help : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Windows/en-US/18667011-c034-43bc-ab2e-0e87bf811e5e/windows-7-increase-the-limit-of-concurrent-tcp-connections-not-related-to-eula-file-sharing?forum=w7itpronetworking

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this:

```
 using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {..
}
```

Each of these uses a new socket.
Use a single httpclient, e.g. a static one

Comment: I would think that we only aggrevate the issue, parallel actions trying to use the same socket all (almost)at once

Comment: can you elaborate on where this limitation is coming from,
why should we care that we open 200 sockets ?
is there a "Socket pool" we can use instead?

Comment: @TomerW see here for example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shacorn/2016/10/21/best-practices-for-using-httpclient-on-services/